# PHP, Put unknown number of column into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an sql table like this:

column: usersid right1 right2 right3 right4 rightX
value:    1      1       0     0        1      x 
value2:      2      0       1      1        1      x

How should I put the rights and their value into an array?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysql.php

Comment: @appl3r You should probably read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) since this structure looks a little off.

Comment: are you trying to insert or update?

Comment: I wanted to put the user rights into an array, so i can decide what page can be shown to the user on the admin

Comment: am confused, are you asking how to insert the data or select and show a page based on the results?

Comment: Select and show a page based on the result.

Comment: in that case jensgram's answer is the way to go. Just run the query at the start of the page, then load the rest of the page based on the result.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a comment, a little [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) might come in handy. Off the top of my head:

```
users (id, nick, ...)
rights (id, name, desc, ...)
users_rights (user_id, right_id, issue_date, expiry_date, ...)
```

Then you could select by `JOIN`ing the tables:

```
SELECT
    ur.user_id,
    r.name
FROM
        rights AS r
    LEFT JOIN
        users_rights AS ur
    ON
        ur.right_id = r.id
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

For a generic insert solution, create a function that takes a hash array,
E.g.

```
$my_array = ('userid' => value1, 'right1' => value 2, etc...);
```

then pass it into a function like;

```
function create($values) {
        // get the arguements passed
        $elements = func_get_args();
        // initialise the array for the paramters
        $sql_array = array();
        // initialise the bindings array
        $bindings = '';

        // start the sql
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->db_table}` (";

        // loop over the parameters
        foreach ($elements[0] as $k => $v) {
            // add to sql statement
            $sql .= "`$k`,";
            // add to bindings string
            $bindings .= "?,";
            // add to sql parameter array
            $sql_array[] = $v;
        }

        // remove the last ' from the sql statement
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
        // now add closing bracket, and start of values
        $sql .= ") VALUES (";
        // remove the last ' from the sql statement
        $bindings = rtrim($bindings, ',');
        // now add bindings to the sql, and close it off
        $sql = $sql . $bindings . ')';

        // run the query in your preferred method, remembering to check for errors
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, data normalization is your friend here, but if you really have to:

```
$res = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM ..." );
$rights = array();
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $res ) ) {
  $rights[$r['usersid']] = $r;
}
```

You can now access the users' permissions through `$rights[<userid>]['rightsX']`